# Blender 2.8 - Transparent background

Tags: hdri

How to make transparent background in blender 2.8 with HDRI on? 
After selecting "Film" - "Alpha" -> "Transparent"
I still have my HDRI on the rendered image

Please help

Answer (score 7):

### Transparent Background

In general - *Render Properties* - *Film* - **Transparent** works (viewport and render)

[image]

To *Save* render with transparency - *Render Properties - Output - File Forma*t - **PNG** and *Color* - **RGBA** has to be set (or any other format that supports alpha channel).

---

### Hide Background

For viewport you can hide background image in *Shading* properties by changing **World Opacity** set to zero.

[image]

Notes:

- Works for *Eevee* and *Cycles*
- *HDRi* is file format, but important in terms is that background in blender use *equirectangular* texture type. It doesnt has to be necessarely HDRi that refers to a high dynamic range image.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting the color of the output to RGBA?
I had a similar issue and this seemed to fix it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you try to render a final output (F12) but it is working, inside the viewport is not. But in the final render it is

[image]

Good Luck

Comment: You're right! But is it possible to disable this image in preview? I have very bright HDRI in my scene (and i need taht bright) and it's very annoying to see something different than in final render

Comment: Not that i know, sorry, you could try to bake the indirect Light (Render Settings>>Indirect Light>>Bake indirect Lighting.